# Java script click event - how to find the child element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a parent element which has many child elements inside it.

```html
<div id="p">
    <div id="c1">
        <div id="c2"></div>
        <div id="c3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="c4">
        <div id="c5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on any of the child element, how to make the child itself and parent be selected?

Comment: What do you mean by "be selected"? What are you expecting to happen when you click? Also this: `</div id="c4">` is not valid HTML. You can't put an id in a closing tag.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish here.  On top of that, you have angularjs as a tag, but you are probably not making good use of the tools angular provides if you are trying to rely on identifying DOM elements by their `id`; that's simply not how angular works at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seem not be very clear, but if i can guess what you want to achieve is something of this snippet

```js
var parentElements = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
        for (var i = 0; i < parentElements.length; i++) {
                 //for each one 
            var childElement = parentElements[i];
            //also you can get the class or other attrb
            var childEleClass = childElement.getElementsByClassName('btn-   floating')[0];
            // perform so stuff with it also
            childEleClass.onclick ......
         
       }
```